# react hook form validation is not working after paste value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I created a model for a form which maps throught it to create form using react-hook-form

when i submit form for the first time, everything is Okay. but for the other times, when i paste a value into inputs, validation not work correctly(it shows required error but the input is not empty)

this is model:

```
export const formData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: "text",
    labelRequired: true,
    label: "name",
    shape: "inline",
    placeholder: "name",
    name: "nameOne",
    validation: {
      required: true,
      minLength: 8,
    },
    size: 6,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "text",
    labelRequired: true,
    label: "family",
    shape: "inline",
    placeholder: "family",
    name: "nameTwo",
    validation: {
      required: true,
      minLength: 8,
    },
    size: 6,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    type: "checkbox",
    label: "Sample",
    shape: "checkbox",
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    name: "checkbox_btn",
    data: [
      {
        id: 41,
        inputId: "inline-form-1",
        label: "1",
      },
    ],
    size: 12,
  },

];
```

the map method to create form based on model:

```
const Sample = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
  });

  const submitHandler = (data, e) => {
    e.target.reset();
    console.log(data);

    reset();
  };

  const mapForm = formData.map((item) => {
    if (item.shape === "inline") {
      return (
        <InputContainer
          key={item.id}
          register={{
            ...register(item.name, {
              required: item.validation.required,
              minLength: item.validation.minLength,
            }),
          }}
          validation={item.validation}
          placeholder={item.placeholder}
          label={item.label}
          size={item.size}
          error={errors[item.name]}
        />
      );
    }
    if (item.shape === "checkbox") {
      return (
        <CheckBoxContainer
          key={item.id}
          label={item.label}
          data={item.data}
          register={{ ...register("medium", { required: true }) }}
          error={errors.medium}
        />
      );
    }
  });

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Breadcrumb parent="Dashboard" title="Default" />

      <Container fluid={true}>
        <Row>
          <Col sm="12">
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <h5>Sample Card</h5>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)}>
                  <Row>{mapForm}</Row>
                  <Button type="submit" className="m-t-40">
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </Form>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Sample;
```

Also there are some container components for wrapping inputs like:

```
const InputContainer = ({
  id,
  register,
  error,
  label,
  labelRequired,
  size,
  type,
  placeholder,
  validation,
}) => {
  return (
    <Col lg={size} style={{ marginTop: "-10px" }}>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label className={`col-form-label`}>
          {label} {labelRequired && <span></span>}
        </Label>
        <Input
          className="form-control"
          type={type}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          {...register}
        />
        {error && error.type === "required" && (
          <p className="p-16 text-danger">this filed is required</p>
        )}

      </FormGroup>
    </Col>
  );
};

export default InputContainer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked that deep into it to find out if this happens from a simple misuse of the `useForm()` hook, but here's what I've figured out.

According to the source code, `register()` returns the following interface (unrelated stuff omitted):

```
type UseFormRegisterReturn<...> = {
    onChange: ChangeHandler;
    onBlur: ChangeHandler;
    ref: RefCallBack;
    ...
}
```

As you can see, this means only the `onChange()` and `onBlur()` events are being registered. `onChange()` is the one we're interested in.

After some quick testing, I've realized that for some unknown reason (maybe a browser bug? no idea), in certain conditions `onChange()` doesn't trigger when pasting text with `CTRL+V`.

Luckily, the regular `onInput()` event still triggers, so we can simply define this event using the `register.onChange()` handler:

```js
<Input
  className="form-control"
  type={type}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  {...register}
  onInput={register && register.onChange}
  // TypeScript
  // onInput={register?.onChange}
/>
```

If `onInput()` is already being used:

```js
<Input
  className="form-control"
  type={type}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  {...register}
  onInput={e => {
    doOtherStuff(e);
    if (register && register.onChange) {
      register.onChange(e);
    }
    // TypeScript
    // register?.onChange(e);
  }
/>
```